# Simplficando comparações encadeadas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, pep8

Segundo o pycharm (que está com as configurações padrões para pep8) diz que é possivél simplificar está linha.

```
        elif student['averange'] >= 5 and student['averange'] < 7:
            student['situation'] = 'Recuperação'
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: eu acho curioso que pessoas que não tem o conhecimento o suficiente da linguagem para entender qual poderia ser a resposta dêem um voto negativo pra pergunta. Não é por que você não sabe que não estão todos os elementos que permitem a resposta correta na questão, e ela é admite uma resposta correta, tranquilamente.

Comment: Alterei o título pra ficar mais genérico e mais pessoas poderem chegar na pergunta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Porque Python tem uma feature muito legal de comparações que permitem que mais de uma comparação com o mesmo elemento sejam escritas na mesma notação que usamos em matemática. Então, se queremos saber se um número está entre "5" e "7", em vez de escrever "se x > 5 e x < 7", como pensamos ao programar, dá pra escrever "se 5 < x < 7", como fazemos em matemática. Internamente, o Python transforma isso em 
"5 < x and x < 7".

Sua linha então ficaria assim:

```
elif 5 <= student['averange'] < 7:
```

Comment: Tem alguma restrição de versão do Python?

Comment: Não - isso funciona há muito tempo, pelo menos desde o Python 2.2

Comment: Poxa, não sabia, interessante vou começar a usá-lo agora ;)

Comment: Intessante, não sabia que dava pra fazer isso!Como é feita a conversão?

Comment: Na verdade é feita pelo compilador do Python diretamente. Ao encontrar a < x < b, ele, internamente, duplica o valor de x, guarda essa cópia, compara a < x, se for verdaeiro, ai compara x < b, senão já anota o resultado como falso. (internamente o código usado para o  "and" nem chega a ser usado - as duas comparações são feitas diretamente em sequência)